# Applescript - Poor performance iterating all iTunes tracks in the library

Tags: performance, applescript, itunes, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to check which tracks are located in my iTunes library directory and which are not using AppleScript.

The following script is really *slow* taking about 2 seconds for each tracks (there's about 8000 tracks in the library) :

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes"

        repeat with l in (location of every file track)
                set fileName to (POSIX path of l)
                if fileName does not start with "/Users/user/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/" then
                        log fileName
                end if
        end repeat

end tell
```

Also tried the following, but same performance:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes"

        repeat with l in (location of every file track)
                POSIX path of l does not start with "/Users/user/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/"
        end repeat

end tell
```

Meanwhile iTunes becomes pretty unresponsive.

Must be doing something silly  but can't figure out what.

This is under OS X El Capitan on a 2015 27' iMac.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dramatically speed up the script by using the keyword `get`

```
repeat with l in (get location of every file track)
```

The difference is:

- without `get` the list is retrieved in each iteration
- with `get` the list is retrieved once

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Sending lots of Apple events is expensive. `repeat with l in (location of every file track)` sends a separate `get` event for each track (`get location of file track 1`, `get location of file track 2`, …). Get the list of all locations first, then iterate over it.
2. Due to crappy implementation, the time it takes to get an AppleScript list item increases linearly with the length of the list; thus performance when iterating large lists goes in the tank (`O(n*n)` instead of `O(n)` efficiency). You can bring it down to `O(n)` with a nasty hack, refering to list items via reference (e.g. by sticking the list in a script object property, then referring to that).

Example:

```
set iTunesFolder to POSIX path of (path to music folder) & "iTunes/iTunes Media/"

tell application "iTunes"
    script
        property fileLocations : location of every file track
    end script
end tell
repeat with l in fileLocations of result
    set fileName to (POSIX path of l)
    if fileName does not start with iTunesFolder then log fileName
end repeat
```